# Does the Lenovo M700 Tiny support 3 Monitors at 2560x1440 Each

Tags: multiple-monitors, integrated-graphics, high-resolution

I have already purchased one of these computers for a friend and when I tried connecting it to my 2560x1440 Display it was re calibrating to 1920x1080 Lenovo said that it should support my displays, but they didn't seem very confident with that answer. It may have something to do with the conversion from Display Port to DVI which apparently wasn't Dual Link, but I'm having a hard time finding a simple converter and all of these troubles were with one display not 3?

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you are using a dongle to convert from DisplayPort to Single-Link DVI, you will not be able to display a resolution greater than 1920x1200. 2560x1440 is 16:9 aspect ratio, so it will scale down to 1920x1080 (16:9) instead of 1920x1200 (16:10).

In terms of being able to output to 3 monitors, I do not believe it will be able to do that either. I believe the Lenovo M700 Tiny only has two physical video ports, so you will at most be able to connect 2 displays.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. You can purchase another port with it to allow for three monitors, my real worry is such a large resolution on generic integrated graphics and how to attain the correct resolution when the only provide DP outputs and I have yet to see a non powered DP to Dual Link DVI?

Comment: @MikeR As long as you are not rendering any graphically intense scenes (Gaming, CAD, etc.) tge integrated graphics should be fine for normal desktop use at 2K. As long as you can find a proper dongle, DisplayPort should have no problem passing a 2K signal. Note that Single-Link DVI will not be able to handle 2K resolutions, and VGA is risky at that high bandwith.